# Make apex:image disappear in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

When the apex:image is clicked, I would like the image to disappear. I do not want the entire div to disappear, just the image within it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [CSS display property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) via the [apex:image](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_image.htm) `onclick` something like this should work:

```
<apex:image onclick="this.style.display='none'" ... />
```